# How to update a zf2 view

Tags: jquery, zend-framework2

I'd like to know how to update a view in zend framework 2. I thought I could do so, just by calling a second time the Action wich constructed the view. But it doesn't seems to work.

So here's the story, I display a table (FYI, it's a planning), and I'd like to insert some elements in this table when people click links like "next month"/"prev month" etc. And so I thought, "hey I might just call my action again, with an argument, doing so I will even avoid to rebuild the entire table, I'll just get from my db the "next month"/"prev month" informations".
But the code acts weirdly, the table constructs itself correctly the first time when accessing the page, but when I try to click on a "nextmonth"/etc link, the view doesn't update itself.
But again, using the JS function succes, I can see that the action is called correctly and return the correct updated view wich should be displayed... but is not displayed, it's still the original view instead.

A little bites of code to help you understand:

the action wich create the view:

```
public function projectAction( )
{
    $mod=$_POST['mod'] ;

    if ( $mod == NULL )
    {   
        //create and populate $tableRes
    }

    else // mod != NULL
    {
         echo "fooooooooooooo, I'm a test !!!" ;
        //modify $tableRes using mod value 
    }


    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
                                     'projectTable' => $tableRes ,
                                    )
                              ) ;
    $viewModel->setTerminal(true);

    return $viewModel ;
}
```

the view:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/projet_b_JS/animation.js')
                              ->prependFile($this->basepath() . '/js/projet_b_JS/projectListener.js')
?>

<table id="projectTable">
<caption> Tableau Projet </caption>
<?php
    //print the projectTable/$tableRes table
?>
</table>

<a onClick='rigTable(-1)'> prev Month </a> <a onClick='rigTable(+1)'> next Month </a> <br />
<a onClick='rigTable(-12)'> prev Year </a> <a onClick='rigTable(12)' > next Year </a> <br />
```

the AJAX call:

```
//inside animation.js
function rigTable ( $mod )
{
  $.ajax({ type : 'POST',
    url : './application/project/project',
    data : { mod : $mod } ,
    success : function ( testReturn )
          {
             alert(testReturn) ;
          },
          error : function ()
         {
                 alert("error from rigTable JS function <br />") ;
         }
      }) ;
}
```

And so, when I click I've got an alert poping up and telling me something like:

```
fooooooooooooo, I'm a test !!!
//rest of the view code
```

I searched for a refreshView() method but didn't find any. I'm certainly doing this the wrong way, thinking too much outside the box, but I don't see other way to do it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot just for reading that long post.

PS: I'm still new to the zf2 framework, and I'm not really used to the "MVC framework programmation neither". Therefore, sorry if it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the samsonik tutorial comfort me in the idea that there is no correct refresh method. So I skirted the problem. I feel kinda dumb for not have thought of this earlier ...
I just modified my JS succes part to:

```
success : function ( testReturn )
 {
    $('#project').html(testReturn) ;
 },
```

Works like a charm. But I might still be missing something, I'll take a closer look later. I've got to move on now :/.
Thanks for the hint Tounu (can't vote you up sorry, need 15 reputations blablabla).

Answer (score 1):

First thing, don't do that :

```
$mod=$_POST['mod'] ;
```

If you want to get your POST variables, use the Request object !
https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.http.request.html

So you'll have something like

```
$mod=$this->getRequest()->getPost('mod');
```

And for your error, it sounds strange... I'd think this might be a problem with your $tableRes algo.
Try to pass a string just to test that the view is actualy "refreshed".

Something like :

```
if($mod!=NULL){
  $tableRes="blablabla";
}
else{
  $tableRes=array().....
}
```

If it does print the table instead of the string, then this may be complicated :p.

EDIT : Meh, I read too fast. You want your table to be refreshed using AJAX ? I'd advise you to try without AJAX first (with a reload of the page).

Currently, your Viewmodel object that you want to be displayed is "stored" in your testReturn variable. Didn't use AJAX so far in ZF2, but I think you're doing it wrong :p. A quick search on the internet lead me to this tutorial. You may find your answers there :
http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/zend-framework-2-using-zend-form-and-ajax/

This is about a form, so your case should be easier ;)

Comment: I already tried something like
if ( $mod == NULL )
    $tableRes = "teeeeeeeeeeeest" ;
else
    $tableRes = NULL ;


But the view doesn't refresh neither.

PS: I'm gonna try to use the request object.

Comment: OK, I'll read this and come back after to let you know if I managed to get it working. Thanks for the support.